# Flutter returns `lifecycle-common-java8.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0)` error

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-lifecycle, androidx

Flutter project won't run in Android Studio with `AndroidX` compatibility and returns following errors in Run/Console window:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':flutter_keyboard_visibility:javaPreCompileDebug'.
>     Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_keyboard_visibility:debugCompileClasspath'.
>     Could not find lifecycle-common-java8.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0).
>      Searched in the following locations:
>          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common-java8/2.0.0/lifecycle-common-java8-2.0.0.jar

And

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'path_provider'.
>     SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you faced those errors just do the following steps:

1. open Android project in Android Studio (u can open a File or Class in android path then select `Open for Editing interface Android Studio` like next image)

[image]

2. In `Build` window select error line then in right side select `Affected Modules`:

[image]

3. For each modules in opened files (`build.gradle`) add `lifecycle-common-java8` api inside `dependencies{}` section and then Build project:

   ```
   dependencies {
   ...

    api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"

   }
   ```

[image]

4. Finally close Android project and run Flutter project.

Comment: This issue is fully related to gradle dependency sync process (So it's either network or cache). Your answer was not the actual solution to your problem.